# Debian PPA from Remi

Tags: apt, yum

I'm looking for the Debian version of a redis package that's currently installed in my CentOS machine

```
redis 2.8.13-1.el6.remi
```

Where do I look for the same version for debian?

I tried querying in search engine "redis 2.8.13 debian" but didn't get any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is available in Debian as the [`redis-server`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/redis-server) package; Debian 10 has version 5.0.3.

If you specifically need a Debian package for version 2.8.13, you’ll find it on [snapshot.debian.org](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/redis/2%3A2.8.13-3/).